# Google Goggles Battery use

Tags: battery, google-goggles

I have not even opened the google goggles app in several weeks. Why does my phone report that it is using such a large amount of my battery? This is especially disconcerting considering that this app has the ability to analyze images which it could be taking without my knowledge or consent. Anyone else ever experienced this?

[image]

Comment: That's very strange.  I have the latest version of Goggles (1.4) installed and it doesn't even have a running service.  Doesn't show up in my battery log.  What version do you have?

Comment: I had this once, restarted then haven't seen it since. Weird bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had similar issues with Google Goggles, the Android API Demo app, and one or two other apps.  I strongly believe this is just a bug in the battery statistics, as it has never impacted my battery life in a meaningful way.  Usually the way I make this go away is by rebooting the phone, although that is not ideal.

Comment: I agree, it is bug. Sometimes I see "Bluetooth" in battery usage which I never enable. (HTC Desire official 2.3.3)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem,to me it looked like battery stats issue, i discharged my phone completely and then recharged it. That solved problem with my phone.